# Which fields are available for querying in Outlook filters?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, email-filter, query

You know it is pretty obvious to use the following filter in Outlook list view:

[image: from:smith]
`from:smith`

But you can also use less-known field names (Microsoft says they are actually *keywords*) like:

[image: from:smith hasattachments:yes about:chris]
`from:smith  hasattachments:yes  about:chris`

My question is how can I **find reference list of all such fields/keywords which can be queried?** (Best including their data types, to make obvious, whether the value is string, numeric, date or true/false). Can it be completely derived just by exploring the Outlook? Or is there some reference help page?

I found a [page with some examples](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Learn-to-narrow-your-search-criteria-for-better-searches-in-Outlook-d824d1e9-a255-4c8a-8553-276fb895a8da) which confuses me, because abovementioned keyword `about` is *not a field* in Outlook, but kind of more complex search criteria, obviously searching multiple fields at once.

Practical use: Is there possibility to set up filter for specific attachment name or extension? Having reference available, I could quickly learn whether yes or no. (EDIT: In the meantime I learned this can be achieved using `attachment` keyword, but again, what about complete list instead finding bits of information there and there?)

Comment: Wow, my question just received off-topic flag + DV. How is this one different from other Outlook questions? I need to enhance my mail-filtering skills but cannot find list of fields available for filtering.

Comment: I'm not aware of any other list but isn't that list already quite comprehensive? Is there anything missing from it you'd need? You could use the [advanced search](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-a-message-with-Instant-Search-56c08e23-8035-4ce9-99f3-ca444848a99c) to come up with some more fields but I'm not sure you can use them on the quick search. In addition [this](https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/searchcommands.htm) page has some more information on the data types.